# How to create a special graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I wish to generate an undirected lattice graph $G$ with following features:

1. It has $m\times n$ vertexes;
2. Each vertex has only two kinds of labels ($0$ or $1$);
3. Every $t\times t$ subgraph is unique.

Set the parameters $m,n,t$ as you needed, but obviously, larger $m,n$ and smaller $t$ would be better.

For example, if the array of the vertex labels of a lattice graph $G$ is

```
1 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1
```

then any $3\times 3$ subgraph of $G$ is unique (only one isomorphism can be found). For example, subgraph

```
1 0 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
```

must be the top-left block of $G$, $90$ degree rotated.

Actually, I can generate such graphs by wave function collapsing. The example above is generated in this way.

---

However, I want to go further. Here are the true questions:

1. If the subgraph can be any shape, how to generate the graph $G$ (every subfigure with $t$ vertexes is unique, whatever the shape is)?
2. What if graph $G$ is not limited in lattice shape?

Any idea or keyword?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but wouldn't $t$ have to have a lower bound dependent on $m$ and $n$, since $1 \times 1$ subgraphs could not be unique for any graph with more than 2 vertices?

Comment: @BSplitter Yes, there is not strict constraint on the parameters, but obviously, larger  $m,n$ and smaller $t$ are better. For lattice subgraph, I have achieved $t=3$, $m,n=13$. But for subgraph with any shape, I have no idea.

Comment: To check, for subgraph, must the rows and columns be consecutive? If not, in your example of $ m, n = 13, t = 3$, then there are ${13 \choose 3 } ^2 = 286^2$ subgraphs, but only $ 2^{3^2} = 512$ possible $3\times 3 $ graphs.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, the rows and columns should be consecutive. More general, the subgraph must be connected.